# Pairwise list modification in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to write a `modifyList` function which takes a list of data structures, modifies them using a function `modify` and return that modified list.
The problem I’m having is, that my `modify` function takes pairs of elements from a list and applies changes to both elements.

This is my (simplified) code so far:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.List

data Structure = Structure{ factor :: Double
                          , position :: V.Vector Double
                          } deriving (Show)

-- Calculates a factor with values from both structures
calculateFactor :: (Structure, Structure) -> Double
calculateFactor (p, q) = (factor p) + (factor q) -- This calculation is simplified     

modify :: (Structure, Structure) -> (Structure, Structure)
modify (a, b) = ( a { position = V.map (+ structureFactor) (position a) }
                , b { position = V.map (subtract structureFactor) (position b) })
            where structureFactor = calculateFactor(a,b)

modifyList :: [Structure] -> [Structure]
modifyList l = [ ??? | (p, q) <- (map (modify) pairs)] -- What do I need to do here?
             where pairs = [(x, y) | (x:ys) <- tails l, y <- ys]
```

How can I make these modifications so that subsequent function calls can work with the updated values?

As an example, I define some data like this:

```
p = Structure 2 (V.replicate 3 1.0)
q = Structure 3 (V.replicate 3 1.0)
u = Structure 4 (V.replicate 3 1.0)
list = [p, q, u]
```

Now `modifyList list` should call `modify` for each element pair in my list: `(p, q) (p, u) (q, u)` which gives me a result list of pairs:

```
[(Structure {factor = 2.0, position = [6.0,6.0,6.0]}, -- Modified p
  Structure {factor = 3.0, position = [-4.0,-4.0,-4.0]}), -- Modified q
  (Structure {factor = 2.0, position = [7.0,7.0,7.0]}, -- Also modified p
  Structure {factor = 4.0, position = [-5.0,-5.0,-5.0]}), -- Modified u
  (Structure {factor = 3.0, position = [8.0,8.0,8.0]}, -- Also q
  Structure {factor = 4.0, position = [-6.0,-6.0,-6.0]})] -- Also u
```

But what I actually want to end up with is the same list with `[p, q, u]` where `p` has `position = [12.0, 12.0, 12.0]` as if I had manually called `p' = fst(modify (p, q))` and then call `p = fst(modify(p', u))` to give the original `position p` a *new* value. Respectively `q` should have `position = [3.0, 3.0, 3.0]` and `u`, `position = [-12.0, -12.0, -12.0]`.

A pseudocode for an imperative language could look like this:

```
Structure = {Double factor, Vector position};
Structure[] list = {p, q, u};
for i = 0; i < list.length; i++;
    for j = i+1; j < list.length; j++;
        structureFactor = calculateFactor(list[i], list[j]);
        //Destructive updates
        list[i].position += structureFactor; //Add factor to each vector value
        list[j].position -= structureFactor;
```

I've tried experimenting with Mutable Vectors but failed trying to include these in my data structure, since my understanding of Haskell is too basic and I'm not even sure if this approach makes sense.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you want here. You say you want to call `modify` to produce a new list. In the `[p, q, u]` case for instance, what you do want the actual result list to be? Because you just list a bunch of function calls and don't describe how you want them to be composed.

Comment: Ah yes maybe I should have worded that better, I want that my `modifyList` function produces a modified list using my `modify` function. The example below was just to illustrate what `modifyList` is supposed to do and what my issue is.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're attempting to do. Please add a simple example with e.g. some number-modifying function.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also having a hard time understanding the objective. I agree that a simpler example, where you can show some example input and expected output, would probably help clear things up.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want: your first list comprehension is essentially a `map`, but probably you want some fold (`foldr`?) or some map variant like `mapAccumL / mapAccumR`. You can always use explicit recursion.

Comment: I have added a more concrete example and some Pseudocode. My actual `modify` function is a bit more complex and I hoped to simplify it a bit for you but in essence it just calculates a value to be added to one Structure position and subtracted from the other (which is supposed to be represented by the `factor` value).

Comment: can you tell me what the output of `modifyList [] = ?` and `modifyList [x]`

Comment: `modifyList [] = []` and I assume `modifyList [x]` means a list with just one element, in this case the function would just return the same list like `modifyList [x] = [x]` or `modifyList(x:[]) = [x]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this is what you want to do: have a function which for each pair of elements of your list (in the same order as in your list), evaluates some modify function on that pair and then puts the results back where they came from.

```
mapPairs :: ((a,a)->(a,a)) -> [a] -> [a]
mapPairs f [] = []
mapPairs f (x:xs) = s : mapPairs f res where
  rec a [] = (a,[])
  rec a (y:ys) = let (b,c) = f (a,y)
                     (a',l') = rec b ys in
    (a',c:l')
  (s,res) = rec x xs
```

I think this works but I don't have a computer to hand. However it seems you probably want a different solution to this. Anyway here is how to write `modifyList`:

```
modifyList = mapPairs modify
```

Here is an attempt to actually solve your problem:

```
postFactors' [] = []
postFactors' (x:xs) = case postFactors' xs of
  [] -> factor x : [0]
  a:as -> (factor x + a) : a : as
postFactors = tail . postFactors'
preFactors = scanl (+) 0 . map factor
addPos v f = v {position = V.map (+f) $ position v}
modifyList l = zipWith (-) (postFactors l) (preFactors l) & zipWith addPos l
```

Description: Find the sum of factors from everything before/after each element of the list. Then find their differences. Then add that to the position of each element

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately both snippets do not work on their own. I fixed the second one by removing `& zipWith addPos l` which gives me a list of total factors for each Structure, which is almost what I want. The only issue is that I actually need to call modify to find out what my factor is because it depends on various variables from my structures.
I think the first snippet might work out but I can't fix the errors: https://pastebin.com/ZSpRFmZC . Maybe you could fix it with some online compiler like https://repl.it/languages/haskell ?

Comment: Sorry about that. I wrote those answers on my phone without a Haskell implantation to hand so I'm not surprised they don't compile. I'm going to be away from a computer and even a mobile signal for probably three weeks so I'm afraid I'm unable to correct these. The second version was designed only to work with your description where the modification to the position depended only on the sum of factors before it and the sum after it. If the modification does not affect the factor then this should still work if factor is replaced with a more complex function.

Comment: I've made a slight modification to the first version but it probably won't fix any type errors that might exist. To solve this yourself you need to work out how to express your algorithm in a more functional way rather than attempting to shoehorn an imperative series-of-non-commuting-updates approach into Haskell

Comment: Update: may have fixed clumsy type error in definition of mapPairs. Ghc said it was applied to too few arguments. It was applied to too few arguments